# Twitter Bootstrap doesn't work with PHP

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys I'm using php with MAMP.

Apparently bootstrap isn't appearing in my basic PHP application. I have on index.php file.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Summit</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Summit</h1>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I have bootstrap.js, bootstrap.css, and index.php (containing the code above) in my htdocs folder which appears to be the default directory for using MAMP.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: Why is your script not in your head tag? move it there for a start, then check the console and make sure the file is in the correct location

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Put the script tag into your head, this should work then.

Comment: Oh my god, i have a bug, bootstrap seems to work at home :/

Answer (score 0):

Check that the script is referencing the right directory ..